# Setting Theano as a default on Google Colab

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm working with Google Colab and neuronet. As a backend, I need to use theano, but as far as I know, Colab defaults Tensorflow. I tried to

`import os`

`os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "theano"`

`import keras.backend`

`keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')`

but get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'`.
Downgrading keras doesn't make any effect. How can I solve that?